# What is the correct way to implement an OnClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener

With so many ways of implementing an OnClickListener within Android, I'm wondering whether there's a best practice or a more recommended way of doing it over the others (ie: I remember reading certain ways require more memory than others)?

At the moment I know of four ways to implement the OnClickListener, these are:

1. Make your Activity implement an OnClickListener interface.
2. Inner Class OnClickListener.
3. Inline Class OnClickListener.
4. Use android:onClick attribute in XML definition of a Button.

Out of the four options I'm leaning towards the XML implementation as it seems cleaner, can anyone else give their opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know regarding memory efficiency, but Here's my approach.

1. I don't like it, It requires multiple if-else (or switch) inside your `onClick` if you have multiple buttons
2. I use this if the 3rd option causes my method, for example `onCreate()` to be too big and messy
3. My favorite. it allows you to find out what each button does very easily, but I use it usually if its `onClick` isn't too long, to keep the code readable
4. I hardly use it, it keeps the code cleaner, but I'm not used to this one, since I don't use it in Java's SWING.

But in the bottom line, like @Lazy_Ninja said, it all comes down to taste. All 4 of them works.

I think what matters, when choosing, is keeping the code clean and readable.

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends. At first I used to like the number 1(Make your Activity implement an OnClickListener interface) because the source look neat that way.
 But at the end I settled with 2.Inner Class OnClickListener, because I found it more easier to read and more easier to implement, especially if you use eclipse and know the shortcuts of auto completion.
At the end I think it depends on taste.